# two computers on same network cannot ping eachother nor view NetBios resources

Tags: ubuntu, router, wifi

I'd like to find out the problem of my network configuration

I have network configuration is like in this diagram:

[image: network diagram]

The problem is between laptop1 and laptop2. At first I thought it was samba server problem. I was configuring samba server on one of the laptops and I wasn't able to access the shares from the second laptop no matter what I was doing. After installing/removing/configuring samba-server a couple of times I realized that the problem resides somewhere else.

Laptop configurations:

```
- Laptop1: ubuntu 12.04 
- Laptop2: Windows 7/ ubuntu 12.04 ( dual boot )
- Server : ubuntu 12.04
```

When I do "ping 192.168.0.10" from laptop2, I get "Destination host unreachable". The same situation is when I ping in other direction.
When I access Laptop1 shares from Laptop2, having windows 7 loaded, I get the error message: "Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found."

When I ping "server" or "router" or "wifi router" from any of laptops I get a reply. The same with windows shares, I am able to access "server"s shares from Windows and Ubuntu, from any of my laptops.

Netbios can't function correctly, that's obvious, I am unable to access windows shares between laptops. I assume that on "wifi router" is a miss-configuration, but I can't find what specifically. The "Wifi router" works as Hub + wifi, it is connected to "router" not in WAN port but in LAN1.

Please, help me correctly configure the router to make them *see* each-other, or at least make NetBios work correctly, between laptops, to be able to access windows shares.

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming that Laptop2 will be booted into Ubuntu (we can return to Windows if necessary later). Please post output of `sudo ifconfig` on both Laptop1 and Laptop2 **in full**, followed by output of `sudo iptables-save` on each laptop **in full**. We can proceed from there.

Comment: make sure that NetBios over TCP/IP is enable.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I found the cause. It was the Wireless router miss-configuration, as I suspected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router has client isolation turned on, prohibiting its WiFi clients from talking to each other. Just turn it off. If you specify the make, model, and firmware (if non-standard) of the router, we can tell you the exact location and name of this option.

Comment: Thanks!!! That was the cause. In Wireless Settings is an option **AP Isolation** that was enabled. After disabling, pinging second laptop worked, and I finally was able to access the windows shares. My router is Tenda W308R by the way.

Comment: Settings found here: ![Router setting page](http://goo.gl/aCMvd)